# E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I am facing this issue in my Logcat while I run my android app. Does anyone know about this issue and how to fix it?

The app dones't crash, but when every i try to type something in Google map's autocomplete search bar it closes that activity. and goes back to the pervious one,which display the current location on a google map.

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

This doesnt't work and this issues actually has already been fixed by google.

**android**

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project_seraphim_disease_tracker"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

**dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //new implementation
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
}
```

```
    //google map required variables
    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final float ZOOMING_DEFAULT = 18.0f;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 9999;
    private SupportMapFragment MysupportMapFragment;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient MyfusedLocationProviderClient;
    private GoogleMap MyMap;
    private static final int AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    //local variables
    private Boolean  MyLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private Location Mylocation;
    private LatLng MylatLng;
    private LatLng SearchedLocationlatLng;
    private List<Place.Field> fieldList;
    private String Searchedlocation = "";
    private Place AutocompletedPlaces;
    //widgets
    private EditText editTextsearchlocation;
```

**This is the Edit Text Button**

```
editTextsearchlocation = findViewById(R.id.edittext_SearchBar);
editTextsearchlocation.setFocusable(false);
editTextsearchlocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: initialize place field list");
                fieldList = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ADDRESS,Place.Field.LAT_LNG,Place.Field.NAME);
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: initialize place autoComplete");
                Intent searchPlaceIntent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                        AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fieldList).build(Map.this);
                startActivityForResult(searchPlaceIntent,100);
            }
        });
```

**This is the onActivityResult**

```
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: currently at onActivityResult");
        if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Correct Request Code");
            if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: successfully Obtaining Places");
                AutocompletedPlaces = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: "
                        + AutocompletedPlaces.getName() + ", "
                        + AutocompletedPlaces.getId());
                SearchedLocationlatLng = AutocompletedPlaces.getLatLng();
                Searchedlocation = AutocompletedPlaces.getAddress();
                editTextsearchlocation.setText(Searchedlocation);
            } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Failed To Obtaining Places");
                Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
                Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_FIRST_USER){

            }

        }
    }
```

**i can see this in the log**

```
"onActivityResult: currently at onActivityResult"
```

**and right after this line in the log is**

```
E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Solution was found.

When I try to initialize Places, I used my API_KEY that I stored in the res/values/Strings.
All I did was put the actually api key in the code.

**From**

```
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(),"@string/API_KEY");
```

**To**

```
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(),YOUR API KEY);
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well! I found out that it was because my API was not enabled (Places on Google). It works with the following as well then! :)

```
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(),"@string/API_KEY");
```

Answer (score 0):

The [upper solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62042209/10871900) didn't work for me, because even when the app was not running, I still received the message, meaning it was related to something else. I had to delete the AVD and create it again. It solved the problem.

Comment: What solution do you mean by "the upper solution"?

Comment: Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(),"@string/API_KEY");