# Android cordova app crash at second time with ajax calls

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I hope you can help me.
I've a strange problem with a cordova app for android. It worked for 3 years, 3 days ago without any changes the app crashed in the moment that performed an ajax call, but only if it's the second time that you open the application.
Then if I install the application and I use it, it works fine, but if I close the application and reopen it the error happen on the first ajax call.

I use cordova 9.0.0, anyone have the same problem?

I'm trying to set in the config file xml some settings.

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

and I tryed also with android:usesCleartextTraffic="true".

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: I don't see any error in adb log, and I've no error in chrome debug console. The app crash at the ajax call, only the second time, when we have a sort of cache I think, because if I delete the cache the app works but onfly for the first time, If I close and reopen the app the ajax call cause the crash.

Comment: I doubt this is the origin of your issue

Comment: I found something, I've a Fatal error signal 5 at the second time that the ajax call is calling.

03-09 09:33:16.348 29996 30369 F libc    : Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT)

......03-09 09:33:17.241  4778  4778 E libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
03-09 09:33:17.305  4778  4778 E libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E/libprocessgroup: set\_timerslack\_ns write failed: Operation not permitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039983/e-libprocessgroup-set-timerslack-ns-write-failed-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: It seems to be the latest version of android system webview, if I downgrade the version the ajax call always works. I've the problem only with ajax call authenticated by session token with the latest version of webview.

Comment: Obviously there is a call that crashes before the 2nd ajax call. What is the error in the webview console ?